# Concrete mathematical statements in relation to Choice versus Reinhardt cardinals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, axioms

Harvey Friedman is well known for investigating concrete mathematical statements that requires strong assumptions, i.e. those that can only be interpreted in a strong extension of $\text{ZF(C)}$. My first question:

1. Is there any known example of a concrete mathematical statement that requires the strength of an extension of $\text{ZF}$ that can prove the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal?

My second question is:

2. If we suppose such an example had been put forth, would that constitute a reason to reject Choice?

The idea is that if 1 is true, then this might open the door for many examples of concrete mathematical statements that can only be interpreted in extensions of $\text{ZF}$ that can prove the existence of a Reinhardt cardinal or higher cardinals, but it is known that all such extensions negate Choice. And by then Choice would appear as a restrictive assumption, since it would restrict interpret-ability of concrete mathematical statements, which is the primary goal of foundation after all.

3. What makes us believe in an axiom? is it its formalization ability (i.e. its interpret-ability strength) or its intuitive appeal? so in a situation like the above, which would we favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're leaving yourself too much wiggle room for "concrete mathematical statement".

Is this going to be something like TREE-related statements, or about Laver tables? Is this going to be something like AD? Is this going to be something like "There exists a topological space such that something"?

Yes, there is an issue with defining a "concrete mathematical statement", and arguably $\sf\operatorname{Con}(ZF+\exists\kappa\text{ Reinhardt})$ is *not* an example of a statement that you're looking for. But nevertheless, it's unclear what is a statement that you are looking for.

Now, to your actual question, I don't quite know the answer. I don't think that there has been much research towards this either. You could argue that he failure of the HOD Conjecture requires the consistency of a Reinhardt cardinal, and that the HOD Conjecture is a concrete mathematical statement. But not that much more has been said and done on the topic.

---

For your second question, would you say that you should accept $\sf CH$ because of one of many "weird" constructions? or consequences from Forcing Axioms ($\sf PFA$ or $\sf MM$) should motivate you to reject $\sf CH$?

If your answer is yes to any of the above, then a Reinhardt cardinal may or may not be a reason to reject choice, depending on the type of statement you found, how compelling you found it, and whether or not you want to reject choice. Ultimately, the only reason to reject choice is that you want to reject choice.

Being an anti-Platonist, I can only suggest rejecting the whole view of "accepting or rejecting something".

---

For your third question, it's a combination of plausibility, usability, and our education. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Your statement that "it's clear to everyone" is not true, since I find it perfectly reasonable and even mundane to say that a consistency assertion is a concrete mathematical statement, of complexity $\Pi^0_1$. Perhaps this issue is like the debates about "natural" mathematical statements. I haven't ever seen a robust or even a satisfactory notion of what counts as "natural", and the reality is that people often disagree about what counts as natural. Too often, some people end up rejecting as unnatural mathematical statements arising in an area with which they are simply unfamiliar.

Comment: Joel, I think that we're interpreting "concrete" in different ways, and I interpret it as "natural" in your "quote-unquote" sense. But I also feel that the OP does too. I fear that this is a barrier that you, as a native speaker, is on the other side of the issue for once. :)

Comment: Its not about Platonism really, I'm speaking from a more general foundational point of view. Because of Godel we cannot interpret all mathematics in one theory, but we can interpret all of it in a line of theories of ascending strength, where each theory extends the prior one, now this line of theories is not effectively generated, but still if I come to know that there is an axiom in the theory at the bottom of that line that would impose a limit on interpret-ability of mathematical statements in the high up theories, then I'd reject it.

Comment: @Zuhair: Really? Do you have a proof of that?

Comment: No. I don't. I'm just asking. I want to see the reasoning about such issues.

Comment: @Asaf I am rejecting the idea that there is a meaningful notion of "concrete mathematical statement", just as I reject the notion that there is meaningful notion of "natural mathematical statement".  We can measure the complexity of mathematical statements in various precise ways, such as in the arithmetic hierarchy, and by this measure, consistency assertions come out as being comparatively concrete, if not extremely concrete.

Comment: when I say reject it, I mean with respect to this overall foundational interpret-ability concern. Of course you may not reject it for local issues that doesn't require higher strengths.

Comment: @Joel: Yes, I agree with you on the principle, I just disagree on the terminology. Mainly because there is a majority of non-native speakers in this comments thread, which I think mean-the-same-thing, and you interpret this as a native speaker as something more/less severe than intended.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, but Harvey Friedman was much into this work, about finding fairly natural mathematical statements that require extreme strength. so do you reject this, do you think his quest was not meaningful

Comment: @Zuhair: You're practically asking an open question, and then a super-subjective question. Some people would argue that choice is a reason to reject those statements.

Comment: My main point in commenting was simply to point out that the "it's clear to everyone" statement is over-stated, since in fact there is debate about this kind of thing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes I agree, but if we adopt such an approach, then there is no way to reason about whether Choice is true or not? I mean what if the mathematical statement that was found was very useful in mathematics, would you still hold to Choice? just because of its intuitive appeal?

Comment: @Zuhair: I don't understand "true or not". That's Platonism.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I mean as far as the quest of interpreting concrete mathematical statement is concerned, or more generally as far as interpretability power is concerned, this is my criterion of truth, which is not just limited to Platonism, perhaps I could have said "useful" or "of higher interpret-ability usefulness", but I find true or false to be simpler, especially If one outlines in which perspective those are understood. This can be useful to a formalist as well, since it is about formal interpretability after all.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins, yes I agree with the "is clear to everyone" point you've raised, you are right, it is not easy to judge, it is debatable.

Comment: @Zuhair: This will be the last time I repeat this, and I won't continue this silly circular discussion. If such statements exist, one could argue that they are a reason to reject choice, and another would argue that they are a reason to reject the statements. Formalists don't care about truth, and multiversialists either accept non-choice universes or they don't. In either case, choosing to reject or accept something is based on personal preference. And when running into a statement contradicting your beliefs, you will simply reject it, or change your beliefs. I have nothing more to add.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, thanks for the answer and comments. Though I generally disagree with your statement "ultimately the ONLY reason to reject choice is that you want to reject choice" you made it a personal matter. I think it is usefulness of a principle that makes us reject or accept it. If I found a statement that proves to be very useful in mathematics and logic and perhaps even in science, that can only be interperted in an extension of ZF with a Reinhardt cardinal, then I'll stop clinging to Choice. That's my stance. And I don't think it is just personal. Anyhow